# дескриптор файла

Tags: c, файловая-система

Здравствуйте. Насколько я понял в языке С каждому потоку ввода/вывода присваивается некоторое неотрицательное число - дескриптор. Хотелось бы понять каким образом он используется для идентификации потока и что будет по ходу работы программы если для некоторого указателя на FILE изменить его поле _file (дескриптор). Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Дескрипторы выдает ядро операционной системы. по нему ядро находит нужную инфу в своих таблицах. если изменится _file то понятное дело он при следующих вызовах функций ядра будет туда передан и ядро будет пытаться работать с другим файлом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Насколько я понял в языке С каждому потоку ввода/вывода присваивается
>   некоторое неотрицательное число - дескриптор.

Это не в языке С. Это в ОС *NIX. На самом деле это число не дескриптор, а указатель на файловый дескриптор. Точнее - индекс в таблице файловых дескрипторов, которую ведёт ОС. Три первых позиции в этой таблицы заняты всегда:

- 0 - stdin
- 1 - stdout
- 2 - stderr

В самом дескрипторе есть поле, указывающее на конкретный файл. Записав в это поле некоторое значение, мы можем перенаправить ввод/вывод в другой файл, как это делается с помощью символов '>' и '<' в командной строке.

Начиная с № 3, файловые дескрипторы не имеют фиксированного смысла. Они связываются с конкретными файлами в зависимости от поступающих вызовов open() / close().

Для того, что бы в программе выполнить перенаправление ввода/вывода, можно использовать функцию freopen.

Попытка "по мясу" подменить файловый дескриптор вряд-ли кончится чем-то хорошим...

Comment: **Три первых позиции в этой таблицы заняты всегда**

а это в корне неверно:)

**Они связываются с конкретными файлами** и снова неверно.

Comment: **это в корне неверно:)** - Сказавши "А", неплохо бы сказать и "Б"...  Даже если пишу демон, который полностью отключается от терминала, то всё равно, дескриптор "ноль" это будет дескриптор stdin. Просто там будет прописано, что он отключен. Но НИКОГДА в дескрипторе "ноль" не будет располагаться описание файла, открытого в прикладной программе, по вызову open().

Comment: если дескриптор закрыть, то следующий open может использовать этот  дескриптор. По второму утверждению - за дескриптором может скрываться также сокет или пайп.

Comment: И помимо этого можно просто пересобрать библиотеки с переопределёнными номерами (вот веселья будет!).

Comment: **если дескриптор закрыть, то следующий open может использовать этот дескриптор.** - Вы читали мой ответ? Там описывается эта ситуация. На дескрипторы stdin, stdout и stderr это правило НЕ распространяется.

Comment: Что бы прекратить этот спор, я соглашусь признать Вашу правоту в том случае, если Вы продемонстрируете текст программы (на любом языке), которая ПИШЕТ в stdin, или ЧИТАЕТ из stdout.